# Is there a way to put every configuration file to a config directory rather than root in Node project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, configuration

Lately, I've been creating a chrome extension and for that, I use a bunch of tools and bundlers that requires a config file-usually starting with a dot. In the root directory, everything looks so cluttered, and it takes a few seconds for me to find a file in the root.

```
-----
|__ src/
|__ static/
|__ .prettierc
|__ .prettierignore
|__ .gitignore
|__ .parcelrc
|__ README.md
|__ manifest.json
|__ popup.html
```

What I want to do is to put every config file into a directory named `config/` as I show here.

```
-----
|__ src/
|__ static/
|-- config/
|   |__ .prettierc
|   |__ .prettierignore
|   |__ .gitignore
|   |__ .parcelrc
|
|__ README.md
|__ manifest.json
|__ popup.html
```

How can I achieve this without breaking the normal functionality? Thanks!

I know that some tools lets you define your config file anywhere you want. However, some of them are strict and you can't even rename them. I looked up for the tools I used but I cannot find any information about this issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**1. Use IDE settings to hide config files**

I recommend that you keep them in their default location since it is a common conventation to do so. Instead, you can just hide them and this is what I do most of the time to keep my project structure clean.

If you use VS Code, you can add a `.vscode/settings.json` and hide the files you don't want to see in the explorer tab. You can toggle them back when you need to check or edit any.

`.vscode/settings.json` file content for your case:

```json
{
  "files.exclude": {
    ".prettierrc": true,
    ".prettierignore": true,
    ".gitignore": true,
    ".parcelrc": true
  }
}
```

Similarly, if you use JetBrains IDEs, go to `File > Settings > Editor > File Types > Ignore files and folders` and append the list of files that you want to hide. Your navigator will be much cleaner.

**2. Use a VS Code extension to nest files**

- Install [vscode-file-nesting-config](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=antfu.file-nesting) by Anthony Fu in your VS Code IDE.
- Add these lines to your `settings.json` file:

```json
{
  // keep other settings as they are, and add the following at the bottom:
  "explorer.experimental.fileNesting.patterns": {
    "configs": ".gitignore, .prettierrc, .prettierignore, .parcelrc"
  }
}
```

- Add an empty file named `configs` in the root of your project.
  Finally, you must have something like this which is probably what you are looking for:

[image]

**3. Add flags to commands you run to use a different path for config files**

If you still want to change their location, this might be helpful for you..

When running `prettier` command, add the following flags:

```sh
prettier --config [.prettierrc path] --ignore-path [.prettierignore path]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I was looking for. However, there's one more point I am curious about. If I use the extension, would the structure of the project I push to Github change?

Comment: Literraly nothing will change. The first and second options are changing the behavior of your IDE. The third is just telling prettier (or any other CLI program you use) about the path of your config files. That might be only for the second answer that is about adding an empty file called `configs`, you can add that file to your `.gitignore` so that git doesn't track it and push it to the remote reposiory.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, instead of adding one more empty `configs` file, I aggregate all of them under `package.json` which looks perfect.

Comment: UPDATED: You don't need the extension. You can alter the settings file manually since it is VS Code related. The extension is just modifying your editor's settings.